# Opencv C++ Declaring a matrix of type uint8

Tags: c++, opencv, templates, matrix, typedef

Fairly simple question: I was wondering how to specify the type of a matrix in opencv.  I was looking at this page https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html, which specifies typedefs for float matrices with cv::Mat1f and so on.  I'm not familiar with C++; can I just make my own uint8 matrix using a similar thing they are doing in the typedefs?

`Mat_< uint8 > mymatrix;` or something like that?  Can I make my own typedef?

Answer (score 0):

The standard type in C++ is `uint8_t`, i.e. `Mat_< uint8_t > mymatrix;`. You need to `#include <cstdint>`.

You can also make your own typedef

```
typedef Mat_< uint8_t > uint8_matrix_type;
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in:

```
cv::Mat1b
```

which is defined in `mat.hpp` as:

```
typedef Mat_<uchar> Mat1b;
```

where `uchar` is defined in `interface.h`:

```
//! - uchar  - unsigned 1 byte integer
typedef unsigned char uchar;
```

---

You can also `typedef` a matrix with your preferred type, but you *may* encounter weird errors since its `DataType` (in `traits.hpp`) won't be specified and so it *may* be incompatible with some OpenCV functions.